# How to make that all the pictures were displayed?

Tags: ios

I have TableViewController and ViewController. In 3 cells change pictures depending on the index and intForString in ViewController.
In the first session I work with all cells. In the second I work with one cell. When I go to the third session image stay only to the cell in which I worked the second session. And the other two images disappear. How to make that all the images were displayed?

Comment: What methods is that code in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are asking when you say "How to make that all the images were displayed?"

However, this bit is very wrong:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

The table view data source method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is supposed to configure and return a new (or recycled) table view cell.

The method you're calling in the first line is the table view instance method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. That method only returns a cell if there is a cell on-screen for the specified indexPath.

That won't work.

You want to use code that calls `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`. If you've defined a class for your identifier, that method will always return a valid cell. If not, you need to add code that checks for nil and creates a new cell using the `UITableViewCell` method `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`

Comment: I need to in the third session, all the pictures were showing in cells.
But in the third session only one image shown.